# create a composite from bitmap and video file with FFmpeg or other binary via as3 frontend

Tags: actionscript-3

After receiving much help with reading all the great stackoverflow topics in the past, I finally have to post a question myself.
For a client I need to create some sort of video-editor for dummies,
which has to generate a video file as output.
The editor has to load a movie-file scale and rotate it to a certain degree, and generate a composite video of a background bitmap and the rotated and placed video.
The frontend will be done in Flash/AS3 and has to use some background tools for processing the video.

Can I use FFmpeg to generate such a composite? Or is there any other good background task available?

edit:
update 19.12. ... still did not find a solution... any ideas from others?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ffmpeg is the best tool for compositing. Instead, you could simply have Flash do the compositing, create the frames (as BitmapData objects) and upload them to some server-side script.

Then once all the frames have been uploaded, use Flash to call a second script that will build the video using ffmpeg.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but isnt flash a little low to generate a full-hd movie with bitmapsdata objects?